# Displaying Data from the database taking Order Id as input in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp and I would like to ask you for some help. I built store with MvcMusicStore tutorial help.Now I want to search in the database by using OrderId.As soon as the orderid is and if we click on the submit button it should display the corresponding rows from the database. My method is as follows

```
    public ActionResult SearchOrder(int? myid)
    {
        var s = from sp in db.Railways
              select sp;
        string oid = myid.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oid))
        {
            s = s.Where(st => st.OrderID == (Convert.ToInt16(oid)));
        }
        return View(s.ToList());

    }
```

Also i tired with the code as

```
    public ActionResult SearchOrder(int? myid)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            if (ViewBag.OrderID == id.Value)
            {
                s = s.Where(st => st.OrderID == id);
            }
        }
        return View(s);
    }
```

In the second method when i tried it is neither displaying the contents nor showing the error.
Pls do help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult SearchOrder(int? myid)
{
    var s = from sp in db.Railways
          select sp;
    if (myid.HasValue)
    {
        s = s.Where(st => st.OrderID == myid.Value);
    }
    return View(s.ToArray());

}
```

First your example will not work because `string oid = myid.ToString();` will not be null or empty string if myid is null; Second example will fail `(ViewBag.OrderID == id.Value)` condition and moreover will not compile.